# What data structure or design pattern can I use to resolve this issue

Tags: java, design-patterns, data-structures, queue, heap-memory

I have the following design issue that I hope to get your help to resolve.
Below is a simplistic look at what the code looks like

```
class DataProcessor{
    public List<Record> processData(DataFile file){ 
        List<Record> recordsList = new ArrayList<Record>();
        for(Line line : file.getLines()){
            String processedData = processData(line);
            recordsList.add(new Record(processedData));
        }
    }

    private String processData(String rawLine){
        //code to process line
    }
}
class DatabaseManager{
    saveRecords(List<Record> recordsList){
        //code to insert records objects in database
    }
}
class Manager{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        DatabaseManager dbManager = new DatabaseManager("e:\\databasefile.db");
        DataFile dataFile = new DataFile("e:\\hugeRawFile.csv");
        DataProcessor dataProcessor = new DataProcessor();
        dbManager.saveRecords(dataProcessor.processData(dataFile));
    }
}
```

As you can see, "processData" method of class "DataProcessor" takes DataFile object, processes the whole file, create Record object for each line and then it returns a list of "Record" objects.

My problem with "processData" method: When the raw file is really huge, "List of Record" objects takes a lot of memory and sometimes the program fails. I need to change the current desgin so that the memory usage is minimized. "DataProcessor" should not have direct access to "DatabaseManager".
I was thinking of passing a queue to "processData" method, where one thread run "processData" method to insert "Record" object in the queue, while another thread remove "Record" object from the queue and insert it in database. But I'm not sure about the performance issues with this.

Answer (score 1):

Put the responsibility of driving the process into the most constrained resource (in your case the `DataProcessor`) - this will make sure the constraints are best obeyed rather than forced to the breaking point.

**Note**: don't even think of multithreading, it is not going to do you any good for processing **files**. Threads will be a solution if your data comes over the wire, when you don't know when your next data chunk is going to arrive ad perhaps you have better things to do with your CPU time than to wait "until cows come home to roost" (grin). But with files? You know the job has a start and an end, so get on with it as fast as possible.

```
class DataProcessor{
    public List<Record> processData(DataFile file){ 
        List<Record> recordsList = new ArrayList<Record>();
        for(Line line : file.getLines()){
            String processedData = processData(line);
            recordsList.add(new Record(processedData));
        }
    }

    private String processData(String rawLine){
        //code to process line
    }

    public void processAndSaveData(DataFile dataFile, DatabaseManager db) {
      int maxBuffSize=1024;
      ArrayList<Record> buff=new ArrayList<Record>(maxBuffSize);
      for(Line line : file.getLines()){
        String processedData = processData(line);
        buff.add(new Record(processedData));
        if(buff.size()==maxBuffSize) {
          db.saveRecords(buff);
          buff.clear();
        }
      }
      // some may be still unsaved here, less that maxBuffSize
      if(buff.size()>0) {
        db.saveRecords(buff);
        // help the CG, let it recycle the records
        // without needing to look "is buff still reacheable"? 
        buff.clear();
      }
   }
}

class Manager{
    public static void main(String[] args){

      DatabaseManager dbManager = new DatabaseManager("e:\\databasefile.db");
      DataFile dataFile = new DataFile("e:\\hugeRawFile.csv");
      DataProcessor dataProcessor = new DataProcessor();

      // So... do we need another stupid manager to tell us what to do?
      // dbManager.saveRecords(dataProcessor.processData(dataFile));

      // Hell, no, the most constrained resource knows better
      // how to deal with the job!
      dataProcessor.processAndSaveData(dataFile, dbManager);
    }
}
```

[edit] Addressing the **"but we settled on what and how, and now you are coming to tell us we need to write extra code?"**

Build an `AbstractProcessor` class and ask your mates just to derive from it.

```
class AbstractProcessor {
  // sorry, need to be protected to be able to call it
  abstract protected Record processData(String rawLine);

  abstract protected Class<? extends Record> getRecordClass();

  public void processAndSaveData(DataFile dataFile, DatabaseManager db) {
    Class<? extends Record> recordType=this.getRecordClass();
    if(recordType.equals(MyRecord1.class) {
      // buffered read and save MyRecord1 types specifically
    }
    else if(recordType.equals(YourRecord.class)) {
      // buffered read and save YourRecord types specifically
    }
    // etc...
  }
}
```

Now, all they need to do is to "code" `extends AbstractProcessor` and make their `processData(String)` protected and write a trivial method declaring its record type (may as well be an enum). It's not like you ask them a huge effort and makes what would have been a costly (or even impossible, for a TB input file) operation a "as fast as possible one".

Comment: thanks for that. actually I used to have something similar. But in my real program, I have many classes extends "DataProcessor" for different types of data. Those classes are being developed by different developers, and the requirement was "Dataprocessor" classes should need nothing more than a datafile and know nothing about "DatabaseManager" class. So I refactored the code to be similar to my mentioned code, but then I got memory problem. and btw I'm still beginner programmer.

Comment: @AnthonyJ. Well, see my extra comments at the end of my answer. If your mates don't agree, you are doomed in regards with this task - no way to get around it.

Comment: alright thanks again and yes this wouldn't require much work on their side. but I'm wondering, why do you think queue wouldn't work? if "Manager" passes queue to "DataProcessor", then "Manager" takes  "Records" out of this queue and pass them to "Database"Manager.

Comment: @AnthonyJ. because your resource bottleneck id *not* the database now, it's the memory, cause by the huge batch sizes. Once you lower the batch size, it *may happen* the next bottleneck to be the DB but **it may not**. That's the nature of a bottleneck: it is "the maximally constrained resource". If you break one bottleneck, you are going to discover another one, less constrained, which you couldn't see before because it was another one "narrower" in front. **Until you don't break the bottleneck in front of you, it is premature to address the next, because you may not know which's the next.**

Comment: that's true, but wouldn't queue with max size of 1024 Record objects (like you did) solves this memory bottle neck problem?

Comment: @AnthonyJ. "but wouldn't queue with max size of 1024...solves this memory bottle neck problem?"  it will with the note 1024 is not a magical number that solves everything. In practice, experimenting a bit, you may find that other values may be more appropriate for max performance. Heck, it may turn out that it will vary with the size of the database - after some pumping in the data, some indexes may become fragmented, or non-optimally balanced - so large batches that were good at the beginning are becoming too large towards the end.

Comment: @AnthonyJ. And I'm not saying that queues aren't useful, I'm saying you cannot say one way or the other until you don't break the memory bottleneck and *the analysis of the next bottleneck reveals queues are a solution for it*. But you'll need to get there first, see that performance is still a problem and analyse why.

Comment: yes sure about 1024, it was just example. and thanks, I have clearer picture now.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use streaming to do this in one thread, one record at a time in memory. The implementation depends on the technology your DatabaseManager is using.

Comment: would you please elaborate? DatabaseManager is using JDBC interface to SQLite and just simple prepared statement where I get values out of "Record" object and put them in "insert" statement, then execute this insert statment.

Comment: here is an example: https://tododev.wordpress.com/2014/08/14/creating-and-object-stream-from-a-jdbc-resultset/